# Calculating the time constant for an RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, transient, time-constant

I have this circuit where \$C1 = 2~\mu F, C2 = 4~\mu F, R1 = R2 = 1~\Omega \$. Here, I want to calculate the time constant of the following circuit.

[image]

I calculated the equivalence resistance and equivalence capacitance as \$R = 0.5~\Omega \$ and \$ C = \frac{4}{3}~\mu F\$. Now, time constant of RC circuit is:
$$t = C \cdot R = 0.5 \cdot \frac{4}{3} = \frac{2}{3}~\mu s \approx 0.667~\mu S$$
But my textbook says that the time constant is \$\frac{8}{9}~\mu s\$. So, where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, the calculated value is correct. Maybe the book's anwers is to another calculated value (it would be a good idea to review what's asking the book).

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla it's written that the time constant (in uS) for the following circuit is (a)18 (b) 4 or (c) 8/9

Comment: Well in that case, I think is a Typo on the book. Your calculation is correct.